# Issue with gitlab's continuous integration with submodules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a several projects that use a common project as a submodule.
The submodule is hosted on gitlab as well, but it is a different project under a different base name.

In each project, the submodule is linked using a git address and not a relative path.

CI builds constantly fail because they claim they don’t have the permissions to pull the submodule.

How can I pass credentials for a submodule in CI? since it’s the same user account, why are credentials even needed?

I get an error like this:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
>   section_end:1558348623:build_scriptsection_start:1558348623:after_scriptsection_end:1558348625:after_scriptsection_start:1558348625:upload_artifacts_on_failuresection_end:1558348627:upload_artifacts_on_failureERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

But after investigation, it's always because the submodule is not pulled.

Answer (score 1):

If the submodule is on the same GitLab server, you **have** to use relative URLs in your `.gitmodules`.

As far as I know, as long as the user triggering the pipeline has the correct permissions to access both projects, the job they trigger should still be able to pull the submodule (as long as it is a relative URL).

From the [relevant documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html):

> If you are using GitLab 8.12+ and your submodule is on the same GitLab server, you must update your .gitmodules file to use relative URLs. Since Git allows the usage of relative URLs for your .gitmodules configuration, this easily allows you to use HTTP(S) for cloning all your CI jobs and SSH for all your local checkouts. The .gitmodules would look like:
>
> ```
>   path = project
>   url = ../../group/project.git
> ```

Note, don't forget to set the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` script.

Comment: So by forcing a relative path, it means that all developers have to put the repo with the submodules in the same folder hierarchy?

Comment: on their local machines? no, because when they do the initial clone of the repository and do the submodule update, git does some magic and I believe it puts the modules in `.git/modules/`

Comment: so that means that git is keeping track, in the submodule folder, of the origin path?